# Erlang client set ssh key

Tags: ssh, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, rsh

I'm using the `:client` API to connect to an external node and use code there remotely, the thing though is that I'm using Dokku for deployment and it would be really nice if I could specify a ssh key at runtime.

Right now my code looks something like this:

```
def start(host) do
  allow_boot to_char_list(host)
  {:ok, slave} = :slave.start(to_char_list(host), :slave, inet_loader_args)
  load_paths(slave)
  {:ok, slave}
end
```

`inet_loader_args == ' -rsh ssh -loader inet -hosts #{master_node_ip} -setcookie #{:erlang.get_cookie}'`

I've tried something like setting the -rsh argument to be `"-rsh ssh -i /path/to/id_rsh"` but it seems to ignore this entirely, I'm not exactly sure how it's implemented and the Erlang docs for `:client` are a little hard to understand for me (I can see it uses `:ssh` underneath somewhere, and that can take a "user_dir" argument which can contain a key file, but I'm not sure how to set that from `:client`)

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry--is that "inet_loader_args ==" the literal code?  If it is that's wrong.  But I'm assuming you mean that's what it is equivalent to.

Comment: You're assuming right :)

Comment: Am I also correct in assuming that you're using single quotes around the value you're assigning to inet_loader_args?  That's an important detail.

Comment: Yes, I'm transforming it with `to_char_list/1`

Comment: To be clear, the code works. The issue is that I'd like to set a custom path for the keyfile rather than the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Looking at [slave.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.2.1/lib/stdlib/src/slave.erl#L372) the `-rsh` argument is passed to `:os.find_executable`, which in your example would look for an executable `ssh -i /path/to/id_rsh`, which obviously doesn't exist.
I think your best bet is to do something like `-rsh /path/to/my/ssh-wrapper` and have `ssh-wrapper` be a shell script that does `exec ssh -i /path/to/id_rsh $@`.

Comment: @MartinS.  That didn't even occur to me, and totally fixes this issue. Thanks. If you want to make that into an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-rsh` option is [intended to point to a different executable](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.2.1/lib/stdlib/src/slave.erl#L106):

```
%% Alternative, if the master was started as
%% 'erl -sname xxx -rsh my_rsh...', then 'my_rsh' will be used instead
%% of 'rsh' (this is useful for systems where the rsh program is named
%% 'remsh').
```

These days people use `ssh` instead of `rsh`. (About 10 years ago the security team on a previous job required `ssh` even when both machines are on the same isolated network.) Since the command line interface is compatible, just pointing to a new executable generally works once you have the keys set up properly. So it makes sense to use the `-rsh` option to point to `ssh` instead.

It also seem logical that the argument could be used to pass other parameters to the `ssh` command as you attempted. However, [the code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.2.1/lib/stdlib/src/slave.erl#L372) assumes the string passed is the name of an executable in your `PATH`. It uses [`os:find_executable`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#find_executable-1) to look for an executable and `ssh -i /path/to/id_rsh` probably doesn't exist.

However, you can take advantage of this feature to point to *any* executable including a shell script. For instance, you could write a `ssh-wrapper` that looks something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
exec ssh -i /path/to/id_rsh $@
```

Then use `-rsh /path/to/my/ssh-wrapper` so that `:slave.start` uses your wrapper with the proper `ssh` options specified. I've found the wrapper technique also makes future maintenance easier as the connection logic stays in one place.

---

Hat tip to [this comment from Martin S.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986632/erlang-client-set-ssh-key#comment56631209_33986632)